# How to make this custom capability work?

Tags: plugins, user-roles, array, user-access

I am trying to make a custom ability on my page CV people can insert and then view their CV I made a custom capability `view_cv` and I want for it to remove the option to view their CV.

```
<a class="edit btn btn-blue" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo __('Check your CV '); ?></a>
```

I would like for it to remove this button, how would I go about doing that?
Thanks in advance!

This was marked as a duplicate but on the other post there are no answers so it doesnt help me!

Comment: @JacobPeattie there are no answers on that post

Comment: And? You didn't even wait 2 hours. It's not even off the first page of newest questions. You can't just post the same question every couple of hours because you're not getting a response. You'll need to be more patient. If you have something to add, edit the original question.